# Closure of symmetric relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I want to show that the symmetric closure on a relation $R$ is the smallest relation on $R$. I wrote the symmetric closure as $R \cup \{(b,a) | (a,b) \in R\}$
Now to prove that the above relation is indeed the smallest relation on $R$, I chose a symmetric relation $S$ that extends $R$ and then wanted to show that  $R \cup \{(b,a) | (a,b) \in R\}$ is a subset of $S$, but I can't figure how.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric closure on a relation $R$? The smallest symmetric relation containing $R$?

Comment: Assuming you indeed mean the smallest symmetric relation, you need to take a symmetric relation $S\supseteq R$, and not just a general relation $S$ extending $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S$ contains $R$ and is symmetric, then for all $(a,b) \in R$ we have that $(b, a) \in S$ by definition of symmetry. Thus, $R \cup \{(b,a): (a,b) \in R\} \subset S$.

Conversely, any symmetric relation containing $R$ also contains 
$\{(b,a): (a,b) \in R\}.$ Thus, we indeed have that $R \cup \{(b,a): (a,b) \in R\} \subset S$ is the smallest symmetric relation containing $R$.

Comment: Does this sufficiently show that the relation is indeed the smallest symmetric relation? Or, is any further steps necessary?

Comment: Yes it does, these are the two inclusions. All you have to do is write it up in your own words.